# how to combine one column cell value with all the other rows of a data-frame python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

please help me to solve this problem.....it means a lot

i want to merge my 'ID' column value with my 'stat.suffix'  column to form one code and combine all the other rows of my data frame in order to get the combination all the other column values to form one complete data frame

**MY_INPUT_FILE:**

just copy paste below data to an excel file

```
Stat.Suffix Article Description Unit of Quantity    ID
    Travel clocks:      9105.29.30
10  Movement    No. 9105.99.40
20  Case    No. 9105.11.10
    Other clocks:       
30  Movement    No. 
40  Case    No.
```

my input :

[image]

Required output:

[image]

```
my 'id' column should concatenate with my 'stat.suffix' column values i.e 9105.29.30 should become 
9105.29.30.10 similarly for all the other 20,30,40 values in stat.suffix values.

As shown in output if my 'id' column have 3 values the entire table will be of 3 times if it has 10 values the same process should happen for 10 times.
```

Comment: Is your ID column part of the same csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross join` by `ID` column with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then join values together with converted to strings:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)

ID = df[['ID']].astype(str).dropna().assign(a=1)
print (ID)

           ID  a
0  9105.29.30  1
1  9105.99.40  1
2  9105.11.10  1

df = ID.merge(df.assign(a=1).drop('ID', axis=1), on='a')
df['Stat.Suffix'] = df['ID'] + '.' + df['Stat.Suffix'].dropna().astype(int).astype(str)
df = df.drop(['ID','a'], axis=1).fillna('')
print (df)
      Stat.Suffix Article Description Unit of Quantity
0                      Travel clocks:                 
1   9105.29.30.10           Movement               No.
2   9105.29.30.20               Case               No.
3                       Other clocks:                 
4   9105.29.30.30           Movement               No.
5   9105.29.30.40               Case               No.
6                      Travel clocks:                 
7   9105.99.40.10           Movement               No.
8   9105.99.40.20               Case               No.
9                       Other clocks:                 
10  9105.99.40.30           Movement               No.
11  9105.99.40.40               Case               No.
12                     Travel clocks:                 
13  9105.11.10.10           Movement               No.
14  9105.11.10.20               Case               No.
15                      Other clocks:                 
16  9105.11.10.30           Movement               No.
17  9105.11.10.40               Case               No.
```

Because in `ID` columns are `nan`s strings solution is changed:

```
ID = df.loc[df['ID'].ne('nan'), ['ID']].astype(str).assign(a=1)
df = ID.merge(df.assign(a=1).drop('ID', axis=1), on='a')
df['Stat.Suffix'] = df['ID'] + '.' + df['Stat.Suffix'].dropna().astype(int).astype(str)
df = df.drop(['ID','a'], axis=1).fillna('')
```

Comment: 18                     Travel clocks:                 
19         nan.10           Movement               No.
20         nan.20               Case               No.
21                      Other clocks:                 
22         nan.30           Movement               No.
23         nan.40               Case               No.
24                     Travel clocks:                 
29         nan.40               Case               No.
30                     Travel clocks:                 
31         nan.10           Movement               No.
i got output like this after number 17

Comment: @austin - hmmm, it means data in input DataFrame are different like in question, in column `ID` or in column `Stat.Suffix`. Can you check it?

Comment: i got this after the line number 17 it have nan.10 etc etc other than that the output is perfect can u please help me with that as well

Comment: @austin - Are data confidental?

Comment: no its the same data and code i have used is ::import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('dummy3.xlsx')
ID = df[['ID']].astype(str).dropna().assign(a=1)
df = ID.merge(df.assign(a=1).drop('ID', axis=1), on='a')
df['Stat.Suffix'] = df['ID'] + '.' + df['Stat.Suffix'].dropna().astype(int).astype(str)
df = df.drop(['ID','a'], axis=1).fillna('')
print (df)

Comment: @austin - I think if is possible share your excel file, because it seems some data related problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203957/discussion-between-austin-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a go

```
import pandas

my_data_frame = pandas.read_csv('my_df.csv')

#get all ids
ids = list(my_data_frame[~my_data_frame['ID'].isna()]['ID'])

#have your dataframe with ID removed
my_data_frame = my_data_frame.drop('ID',axis=1)

merged_df = []
for i in ids:
    #copy your dataframe
    tmp_df = my_data_frame.copy()

    #get rows with stat suffix not as na
    for index,row in my_data_frame.loc[~my_data_frame['Stat.Suffix'].isna()].iterrows():
        tmp_df.loc[index,'Stat.Suffix'] = str(row['Stat.Suffix']) +'.' + str(i)
    merged_df.append(tmp_df)
my_df = pandas.concat(merged_df[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
my_df

Stat.Suffix Article Description Unit of Quantity
0   NaN Travel clocks   NaN
1   10.0.9105.11.10 Movement    No.
2   20.0.9105.11.10 Case    No.
3   NaN Other clocks:   NaN
4   30.0.9105.11.10 Movement    No.
5   40.0.9105.11.10 Case    No.
0   NaN Travel clocks   NaN
1   10.0.9105.99.40 Movement    No.
2   20.0.9105.99.40 Case    No.
3   NaN Other clocks:   NaN
4   30.0.9105.99.40 Movement    No.
5   40.0.9105.99.40 Case    No.
0   NaN Travel clocks   NaN
1   10.0.9105.29.30 Movement    No.
2   20.0.9105.29.30 Case    No.
3   NaN Other clocks:   NaN
4   30.0.9105.29.30 Movement    No.
5   40.0.9105.29.30 Case    No.
```

Comment: sir the ouput is perfect but the Stat.Suffx values are slightly wrong  it should be 9105.99.40.10,9105.11.10.10 not 10.0.9105.29.30